# Prove that unit circle consists of singularity points

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove that unit circle consists of singularities. So I have got two sums: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{n^2}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{n!}$. Radius of convergence of them is obviously $1$ I’ve already proved that point $z=1$ is singularity. How to prove remaining?
(I mean that $\{|z|=1\}$ consists of singularities)

Comment: For the second one, if the series is $f(z)$, then $f(e^{2\pi ik/m}z)$ is equal to $f(z)$ minus a polynomial. So, $f(z)$ is singular at all possible roots of $1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: For the first one, if $f(z)$ is the series, then $2f(z^4)=f(z)+f(-z)$. Observe that $f(z)\to\infty$ as $z\to1$ along the reals. Therefore, from the functional equation, if $z\to w$ radially, where $w$ is a fourth root of $1$, then since $2f(z^4)\to\infty$ it follows that so do $f(z)$ or $f(-z)$. This in turn implies the same conclusion for $16$-th roots of unity, and all $4^m$-th roots of unity.

Comment: I won’t get every point on circle like that

Comment: You get a dense set of points. Note that if a point is regular, then all points in a small enough neighborhood of it must also be regular. Since the singular points found above are dense in the circle, then no point can be regular.